# Gerrit Code Review - Change-Id is not working if I am using sublime-text for commit

Tags: git, merge, sublimetext3, gerrit, nano

Just realize today, if I am using sublime-text instead of nano to commit or amend my changes  willl not allow me to do a  **git review**

```
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:        
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir);       
remote: 
remote: 
To ssh://xxxxxxxx
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master/xxxx (missing Change-Id in commit message footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://xxxxxx'
```

so if I commit my messages using sublime will not include the  Change-Id,

I changed the editor to nano the change-Id will be  include with sucess:

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```

I would like to keep using sublime-text for my commits msg, so someone has a idea to how to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: What does happen when you use the sublime editor? The commit message is correctly created (only the change-id is missing)?

Comment: yes :) the change-id and I can't do the code review

Comment: What are you using (Linux, Windows, Mac)?

Comment: I am using linux ubuntu

Comment: Apparently `commit-msg` hook is not getting called. You can try putting some debug messages in `commit-msg` hook (under `.git/hooks`) to confirm if its even getting invoked. If the editor exits abnormally, it is possible that normal flow is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Sublime editor with the following command?

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

Comment: yes its is already added to the [core] section of the ~/.gitconfig file